# Getting the latest Java Runtime Enviroment parent folder

Tags: windows, batch-file, java-runtime-compiler

I want to make my job a little easier, I tried creating a batch file to get the JRE path. I'm only getting the javaw.exe path. So for example we are using Team Center 10. It has this tem_init and it grabs the folder JRE7 (example version) but people update to the latest version and uninstall. I'm looking to make a batch file that automatically grabs JRE installed.

```
    @echo off 
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    rem Where to find java information in registry
    set "javaKey=HKLM\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment"

    rem Get java home for current java version
    set "javaDir="
    for /f "tokens=2,*" %%d in ('reg query "%javaKey%\%javaVersion%" /v "JavaHome" 2^>nul') do set "javaDir=%%e"

    if not defined javaDir (
        echo Java directory not found
    ) else (
        set TC_JRE_HOME : %javaDir%
    )

:end 
   endlocal
```

I wanna get a path like this `C:\Program Files\Java\jre7`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this, (it assumes that the latest version will be the last returned result):

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "baseKey=HKLM\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment"
Set "regVal=JavaHome"
Set "javaDir="
For /F "Tokens=2*" %%A In (
    '"Reg Query "%baseKey%" /S /F "%regVal%" /V 2>Nul|Find /I "%regVal%""'
) Do Set "javaDir=%%~B"
If Not Defined javaDir (Echo Java directory not found) Else (
    Set "TC_JRE_HOME=%javaDir%")
Pause
```

**Edit**

That seems to `Set` a variable unnecessarily, *this doesn't*:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "baseKey=HKLM\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment"
Set "regVal=JavaHome"
Set "TC_JRE_HOME="
For /F "Tokens=2*" %%A In (
    '"Reg Query "%baseKey%" /S /F "%regVal%" /V 2>Nul|Find /I "%regVal%""'
) Do Set "TC_JRE_HOME=%%~B"
If Not Defined TC_JRE_HOME Echo Java directory not found
Pause
```

*I've added the `Pause` commands just to allow for reading any `Echo`es.*